# Suppressing Log Output for NAnt Delete Task

Tags: logging, cruisecontrol.net, nant

We are currently using CruiseControl.NET with NAnt 0.85 build scripts and while everything is working well, the log files are a little too verbose for my liking.

In particular, when deleting folders using the `<delete>` task I always get a `[delete] Deleting directory` entry in the log.

Fair enough but this task is run in a `foreach` loop and results in a long list of entries (especially if the folders contained files - each deletion is reported) which is just cluttering the log and making it difficulty to read without endless scrolling. I've added numerous `<echo>` tasks to report the scripts progress so don't really need all this 'fluff'.

I've used the `verbose="false"` attribute on the `<delete>` task and while this supressed the file deletion messages (which improved the log readability no end) the folder deletions are still reported. I've tried utilising the `verbose` attribute on the `foreach` but this made no difference.

Does anyone know how I can supress these messages or am I stuck with them .. ?

Comment: I'm interested in the answer as well. BTW: verbose="false" neither makes <copy> or <mkdir> shut up.

Comment: I think the verbose eliminates most of the messages but not those at 'the top of the tree' as it were. So while I don't see every file copy it do get the following: '[copy] Copying 1436 files to 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<appName>'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've looked into this before and it comes down to the internals of NAnt and the way the project's logging threshold cannot be properly controlled (arguably a bug). There has been good conversation around a non-intrusive *workaround* which is to create and consume a new task called **LogLevel**.

A use case would be the following:

```
<loglevel level="None">
    <delete file="helloworld.txt"/>
</loglevel>
```

The first post discussing this was from [Shh, Keep it Quiet](http://jayflowers.com/WordPress/?p=133), by Jay Flowers. There was then a nice [follow up](http://www.neovolve.com/2008/01/16/loglevel-nant-task/) to this post by Rory Primrose. Be sure to check the comments as there is very useful information revealed.

Comment: Bah - Day off today, I'll have to check on Monday. Cheers Scott

Comment: Sorted! I tried the link from Jay Flowers but that didn't work for me. Rorys post however sorted it out and I can now, finally, purge my logs of all this 'fluff'. Cheers

Comment: follow up link not working anymore, but answer still very useful

Comment: The followup link is here: http://www.neovolve.com/2008/01/16/loglevel-nant-task/